# How can I parametrize $|x|+|y|=1$

Tags: geometry, parametric

I need parametrize $|x|+|y|=1$ but I don't know how to parametrize. I know that it is a rotated square, I would like understand so if you can explain to me like if I was still, thanks

Comment: By parametrize, you mean finding a (continuous) function $f$ on $[0,1]$ which is a bijection between $[0,1)$ and the square?

Comment: I did something about it but I don't know if what I did is right. I consider y=1-x, y=1+x, y=-1-x, y=x-1. So... (1-t, t); (1+t, t); (-1-t, t); (t-1,t)

Comment: @Alfrefft Don't forget to check one of the answers if one of them helped you solve the problem, so the problem will be marked as closed.  And provide feedback if you are still having trouble.

Answer (score 5):

Assume we want to find an equation of the form $r(\theta)>0$ that will describe the square, where: $$x= r(\theta)\cos(\theta),\quad y=r(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$We have that:
$$|r(\theta)\sin \theta|=1-|r(\theta)\cos \theta|$$
Or factoring out $r(\theta)$ (since we know $r>0$):
$$r(\theta)= \frac{1}{|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|}$$

To visualize $x(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)$, see below as a function of $\theta$:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: Why not just factor out the $r$ which is always positive, to get $r = \frac{1}{|\cos(\theta)| + |\sin(\theta)|}$ ?

Comment: @DanielV - Thanks for that. That is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the answer that was expected from whoever wrote the question.  I'd suggest a footnote to explain why $r$ can be factored out if you feel like it, since it probably isn't obvious to the poster.

Answer (score 2):

Starting at $(1, 0)$ and going counter-clockwise around the origin, something like
$$
\cases{x(t) = |t-2| - 1\\y(t) = |t-3| - |t-1| + t -2},\quad t\in[0,4]
$$
should work.

Comment: Can you explain me how you did? please!

Comment: @Alfrefft I knew that for the $x(t)$ part, I needed a function that went from $1$, down to $-1$ and back to $1$ again, and it needed to be straight line segments. The $y(t)$ part needed to go from $0$ to $1$, down to $-1$ and back up to $0$. Therefore, I knew that the parametrization had to be primarily linear, with some absolute values in there for the turning points Thus I played around with $x(t) = |t-2|$ and $y(t) = |t-3|-|t-1|$ until I got what I wanted. Using [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to help in the plotting didn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

You observed that all points $(x, y)$ satisfying $|x| + |y| = 1$ is a path forming a diamond.  Since paths are 1-dimensional lines, you can describe the path as a function of one variable, as $(x(t), y(t))$.

One option for defining $(x(t), y(t))$ is to start at $(0, 1)$ at $t=0$, and move counter-clockwise around the origin, with $t=1$ being at $(1, 0)$, and when $t=2$ the path is at $(-1, 0)$, at $t=3$ the path is at $(0, -1)$, and at $t=4$ the path has returned to $(1, 0)$.  That can be written out as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}t \quad &\text{ for } 0 \le t \le 1 \\
%
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}(t - 1) \quad &\text{ for } 1 \le t \le 2 \\
%
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}(t - 2) \quad &\text{ for } 2 \le t \le 3 \\
%
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}(t - 3) \quad &\text{ for } 3 \le t \le 4 \\
\end{cases}$$

If the problem had been a 2 dimensional shape, such as the face of a cube, we would have had to use 2 parameter variables, such as $(x(s, t), y(s, t))$.  But for one dimensional shapes you only need 1 variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use $x = \cos t |\cos t|$, $y = \sin t |\sin t|$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

Comment: Never mind. I was trying to plot it mentally and made a mistake while attempting to rewrite $\sin^2 t$.

Answer (score 0):

$x = t, \; y = \pm \big|1 - |t|\big|$ such that $-1 \leq t \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,0)$, $C=(0,-1)$, $D=(-1,0)$. The locus $|x|+|y|=1$ is the square with vertices $ABCD$.

Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ as follows:
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}
(1-4t)A+4tB & \text{if $0\leq t\leq\frac14$} \\
(2-4t)B+(4t-1)C & \text{if $\frac14\leq t\leq\frac12$} \\
(3-4t)C+(4t-2)D & \text{if $\frac12\leq t\leq\frac34$} \\
(4-4t)D+(4t-3)A & \text{if $\frac34\leq t\leq1$} 
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The most natural parametrization is probably $\gamma:[0,2\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by:
$$ \gamma(t)=\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|},\frac{\sin\theta}{|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|}\right) $$
i.e. the re-scaled circle.

Answer (score 0):

From the implicit equation,

$$y=\pm(1-|x|)$$with $x\in[-1,1]$.

Let $x$ run from $-1$ to $1$, following the lower branch and using a parameter $t$:

$$t\in[-2,0]\to x=1+t,y=|x|-1=|1+t|-1.$$

Then let $x$ run from $1$ to $-1$, following the upper branch:

$$t\in[0,2]\to x=1-t,y=1-|x|=1-|1-t|.$$

We can condense in a single expression

$$t\in[-2,2]\to \\x=1-|t|,\\y=\text{sign}(t)(1-|1-|t||).$$